PayPal Partner Referrals API V2, action_url validity period
I am integrating with the PayPal Referral API, the onboard seller before payment option. Sure, here is your revised text:
In my situation, a user will receive the partner link in an email or from the support team. I couldn't find in the documentation if the user's action_url has an expiration period. If it doesn't, what would be the best way to handle the situation if the user loses the URL? Should I generate a new one with the same tracking ID? Or can I store the action_url once I receive it and resend it if needed?
Please, advise.

Use your own URL scheme. When a user visits the URL you gave them, obtain an action_url and direct them there.

Oh, I see what you mean, that is a good alternative.
